# Auto-increment Visual Studio Setup Project version number

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I use Visual Studio Setup projects to create MSI's for my .Net Applications.  It would be nice if I could have my version numbers auto-increment.  Even better would be an option to set the installer version equal to AssemblyVersion of the primary output exe.

Comment: I don't use VS setup, but something to consider from an MSI point of view... From an upgrade perspective the MSI ProductVersion effectively ignores the 4th field of a version, so if you want to discriminate between product builds to be able to do major upgrades beween them, you'll need to find a way to 'pack' the last two fields into one.

Comment: Good point, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not overkill for you, use a BuildServer (like TeamCity (free for up to 20projects).
With a little msbuild-coding, you can nicely automate the building of your installers (including automatic revision number incr.)

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  Thanks.